# python: удалить все строки в начале txt файла до определённой строки

Tags: python, python-3.x

есть txt файл - надо удалить все строки с начала файла до строки которая начинается с    1.

```
f = open('C:\\test.txt', 'w')
sep = '1.'
f.write(split(sep, 1)[0])
f.close()
```

текст файла примерно такой

```
start in row
5364
test
789

go www
1.
46712341
3412341
4523452
434323342
```

надо чтоб после осталось

```
1.
46712341
3412341
4523452
434323342
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
with open('C:\stest.txt', 'r') as f:
   data = f.readlines()
pos = data.index("1.\n")
with open('C:\stest.txt', 'w') as f:
   f.writelines(data[pos:])
```